# Is there any recommended way to return property values through getters?

Tags: php-extension

I'm playing a bit with writing php extensions and trying to figure out what would be the best way to return class private property value through method (registered by the extension of course).

Here is what I have so far:

```
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(uamqp_connection) {
    // class initialization 
    zend_declare_property_bool(this_ce, "boolValue", sizeof("boolValue") - 1, 0, ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE);

}
```

And then method:

```
PHP_METHOD(Test, getBool)
{
    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    RETURN_BOOL(zval_get_long(zend_read_property(this_ce, getThis(), "boolValue", sizeof("boolValue") -1, 1, NULL)));
}
```

I'm not sure about this `zval_get_long` passed later to `RETURN_BOOL`, is that something that could be considered valid way? Is there any easier/more obvious solution? This one seems to work but I still dont feel confident about it.